# No upload speed using Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I recently bought a new Dell XPS 9560 and I am using it with a dualboot with ubuntu 18.04 and Win10. Everything works fine except of the upload speed in my home network.

Using Win10 I get something like 4.5 Mbit/s for the upload. For ubuntu I only get values below 0.2 Mbit/s (measured with speedtest-cli). Speedtest by Ookla is not even able to measure any upload speed, even though the download speed is fine.

This problem only occurs in my home network while at the university network and other networks everything works fine.

The output if iwconfig is:

```
$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 08:96:D7:74:55:7B   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:50   Missed beacon:0
```

Update: It seems to be that the upload speed does change from time to time. I just tested again and it was a the desired value of 4.5 Mbit/s, half a minute later again down at 0.2 Mbit/s.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with the output of `iwconfig` while connected to your home wifi?

Comment: I solved the problem following the fix described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343/comments/22